# How to work with BLOB contents in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, blob, mysql-5.6

I'm using a BLOB data type to store big array of bytes. Arrays are produced and consumed by C# application, but now I need to edit my BLOB in SQL language.

The question is:

How can I update just one byte in a BLOB field using SQL?

Comment: you can use substr on blob  (at least on the recent version)

Comment: You have BIT operations on MySQL, but byte stuff... I don't remember anything of the like. If you want, you can shift multiple times the byte array